# No data available issue In JQuery Data table With VueJs

Tags: vue.js, datatables

I'm developing a system using C# and Vue Js, I need to show some data in table, for that I have use JQuery Data Table.
In my case all the data and options (search and pagination) is showing but problem is in table's top row showing as **"No data available in Table"** if we do force (Ctrl + F5) refresh then table is working perfectly.

Note : I searched regarding this problem in stack overflow there were some related questions I tried with those but I couldn't figure it out.
Please help me to resolve this problem.

1) after the first page load table is showing like this.

Note :If I searched something in search bar all data get not apear.

[image: First Load Image]

2) after force refresh table is showing like this and working perfectly.

[image]

This is the code's I have use for the implementation.

Vue Component.

```
 Vue.component('all-enquiry', {
    template: ' <table id="allenquiry" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" style="width:100% !important"><thead><tr><th>Date<small>/Time</small></th><th>Hndle.By</th><th>Ref:No</th><th>Name</th><th>Destination</th><th>Dep.Date</th><th>Ret.Date</th><th>Airline</th><th>Status</th><th class="disabled-sorting text-right">Actions</th></tr></thead><tbody class="tbody-text"><tr v-for="enq in enquiryall"><td>{{ enq.CreatedDate | formatDate }}</td><td>{{ enq.HandleBy }}</td><td>{{ enq.EnqRefno }}</td><th>{{ enq.PaxName }}</th><td>{{ enq.DepartingTo }}</td><td>{{ enq.DepartingDate }}</td><td>{{ enq.ReturnDate }}</td><td>{{ enq.Airline }}</td><td><button class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-round">Following Up</button></td><td class="text-right"><button class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-round">More Info</button></td></tr></tbody></table >',
    data() {
        return {
            enquiryall: '',
        }
    },
    created: function () {      
        this.getall();
    },
    methods: {
        getall: function () {
            var enquiryform = this
            axios.get("/Main/getAllenq/").then(function (response) {
                enquiryform.enquiryall = response.data.allenquiry;

            });


        }
    }
});
```

Table Initialization.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#allenquiry').DataTable({
        "pagingType": "full_numbers",
        "lengthMenu": [
            [10, 25, 50, -1],
            [10, 25, 50, "All"]
        ],
        responsive: true,
        language: {
            search: "_INPUT_",
            searchPlaceholder: "Search records",
        }

    });   
});
```

Html

```
<div class="card-body">
    <div class="toolbar">
    </div>
    <all-enquiry></all-enquiry>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe your ajax request not finished when you initialize the DataTables. Create an other method in the component to initialize the datatables. eg: `initDt() {}`

Because of the `nextTick()` it's going to initialize the DataTables when the table render finished.

Code not tested, it should have problems with the scopes, i'm using arrow `() => {}` functions instead of `function()`.

```
Vue.component('all-enquiry', {
    template: '...',
    data() {
        return {
            enquiryall: '',
        }
    },
    created: function () {      
        this.getall();
    },
    methods: {
        getall: function () {
            var enquiryform = this
            axios.get("/Main/getAllenq/").then(function (response) {
                enquiryform.enquiryall = response.data.allenquiry;
                enquiryform.$nextTick(function() {
                    enquiryform.initDt()
                });
            });
        },
        initDt() {
            $('#allenquiry').DataTable({
                "pagingType": "full_numbers",
                "lengthMenu": [
                    [10, 25, 50, -1],
                    [10, 25, 50, "All"]
                ],
                responsive: true,
                language: {
                    search: "_INPUT_",
                    searchPlaceholder: "Search records",
                }
            });    
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use axios on `mounted` and create `datatable` on `updated` life-cycle method

```js
mounted(){
  axios
  .get('/estimator')
  .then(response => {
    this.items = response.data;
    // console.log(response.data);
  })
},

updated(){
  var datatable = $('#datatable').DataTable({
    "pagingType": "full_numbers",
    "lengthMenu": [
      [10, 25, 50, -1],
      [10, 25, 50, "All"]
    ],
    responsive: true,
    language: {
      search: "_INPUT_",
      searchPlaceholder: "Search estimator",
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this table compatible with vue 2 and vue 3

https://www.npmjs.com/package/data-table-vue